# Translating for loop into list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I can get this loop to work properly:

```
for x in range(0,len(l)):
   for k in d:
      if l[x] in d[k]:
         l[x] = k
```

This looks through a list and checks if the value is in any of the dictionary items and then calculates it equal to the dictionary key it is found within (the dictionary contains lists.)

However, I want to convert to a list comprehension or other single line statement for use in a pandas dataframe - to populate a field based on whether or not another field's value is in the labeled dictionary keys and assign it the dictionary key value.

Here is my best attempt, but it does not work:

```
l = [ k for x in range(0,len(l)) if l[x] in d[k] for k in d ]
```

Thanks

Comment: Some loops are easier to read as loops. Comprehensions should not be used if they hide the intent or make the reader stop and scratch the head...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you're after (example data that can be copied and pasted is always appreciated), I'd do something like this:

```
>>> l = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
>>> d = {1: ["a"], 3: ["d", "c"]}
>>> l2 = [next((k for k,v in d.items() if lx in v), lx) for lx in l]
>>> l2
[1, 'b', 3, 3]
```

Don't forget to think about what behaviour you want if an entry in `l` is found in multiple lists in `d`, of course, although that may not be an issue with your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with a list comprehension, because you have an assignment:

```
l[x] = k
```

which is an *statement*, and a list comprehension can't have them.